# I need to make my flexbox items no bigger than my browser window but they ignore height

Tags: html, css

I need to make my flexbox items no bigger than my browser window but they ignore height, tried different methods but it doesn't work, position properties can't be used. And the height of the chat-box should change depending on the height of the header and footer. I can't figure out how this can be done. JS is not allowed.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.main {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    border: solid 3px rgb(161, 129, 129);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: content;
    /* flex-shrink: 1; */
}

.header {
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(50, 4, 4);
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.footer {
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.chat-box {
    /* height: calc(100% - 550px); */
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(72, 0, 255);
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.chat-users {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(203, 110, 110);
    /* overflow: auto; */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chat-window {
    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 239, 146);
    overflow-y: scroll;

    /* overflow: auto; */
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>
                    HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Reprehenderit sed quidem omnis quaerat, obcaecati aliquam cum
                    voluptate numquam, exercitationem similique eaque aspernatur nobis
                    fugit ad molestiae soluta magnam atque in quibusdam sunt doloribus
                    vitae laboriosam esse! Excepturi pariatur iusto perspiciatis dolores
                    alias ipsam asperiores inventore neque facilis labore minima placeat
                    ipsa fugit eaque exercitationem vitae illum sapiente dolor adipisci
                    est, id quis, provident nulla. Inventore distinctio explicabo aliquid
                    tempore saepe, quae asperiores adipisci excepturi quibusdam
                    dignissimos? Iusto, fuga cupiditate. Praesentium impedit ipsa odio
                    magni, rem dolorum magnam laboriosam architecto ut quibusdam corporis
                    odit fuga ea quasi dicta saepe quisquam distinctio?
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="chat-box">
                <div class="chat-users">
                    <p>
                        USERCHAT <br />Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Pariatur deleniti, iure hic quis quasi temporibus incidunt
                        nostrum ab fuga sunt atque. Rem, debitis minima totam nemo iste
                        nobis impedit qui quae laudantium, soluta fugiat natus pariatur,
                        ipsum quasi ut sint. Veritatis tenetur, provident ratione cum
                        reiciendis nisi facilis vero voluptatum. Fuga autem dolorum, dolores
                        esse voluptate voluptatem est rerum expedita debitis repellendus
                        temporibus quasi reprehenderit pariatur eaque explicabo, commodi
                        dolore, porro ad officia ducimus! Minima molestiae, accusamus
                        aliquid quos optio fugit assumenda aliquam nesciunt magnam et,
                        expedita aperiam blanditiis distinctio consectetur sunt saepe
                        eveniet, consequuntur quibusdam facere! Veniam, amet a.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-window">
                    <p>
                        USERWINDOW <br />
                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis
                        dolorum blanditiis fuga minima sequi iusto temporibus laborum quam
                        totam animi nisi excepturi a asperiores porro id quis, neque hic
                        doloremque dignissimos soluta esse ducimus. Architecto omnis eaque
                        ipsa quisquam nam fuga ex a accusantium ullam repellendus
                        necessitatibus impedit, perspiciatis reiciendis adipisci ad ratione
                        beatae eius consectetur optio hic in temporibus? Dolorum non minus
                        iste unde iure perferendis id reprehenderit nobis, vel magni nemo
                        facere quisquam architecto, aperiam vitae numquam voluptatibus quae
                        natus molestiae dolores perspiciatis, ad nisi distinctio! Excepturi,
                        cum unde! Optio veritatis distinctio quod eveniet laudantium,
                        tempore omnis sint reiciendis. Quibusdam animi autem a adipisci hic,
                        cumque impedit, omnis odit nesciunt eveniet voluptas pariatur
                        nostrum laudantium corrupti voluptates aliquid mollitia commodi! A
                        possimus, repellat dolorum enim beatae, tempore ad mollitia quae et
                        quidem veritatis reiciendis tenetur in dicta molestias labore quo
                        laboriosam voluptates maiores cumque unde. Unde, possimus odit! Esse
                        culpa vel laborum ullam exercitationem cupiditate. Quo porro beatae
                        amet accusamus a fugiat. Expedita nobis totam, molestiae fugit neque
                        aspernatur impedit incidunt corporis possimus velit! Nobis aut
                        exercitationem et, incidunt, architecto accusantium voluptates at
                        ratione officiis nisi in itaque consequatur dolorum quisquam velit
                        error, soluta optio quasi. Nobis aliquid aut enim repudiandae iure
                        repellat unde beatae amet distinctio ducimus dolores dolore id
                        delectus et nesciunt ab doloremque, pariatur commodi! Quaerat eos
                        eveniet pariatur! Consectetur consequatur enim voluptatibus sequi
                        perspiciatis. Voluptatum officia quos tempore facilis, quae ipsam
                        nisi consectetur aspernatur, harum consequuntur voluptatem rerum
                        temporibus, praesentium distinctio libero atque. Natus, explicabo
                        illum repellat quisquam corrupti provident voluptatum iusto
                        consequuntur tempora, quibusdam, obcaecati maxime. Repudiandae vel
                        cum animi! Eius, in possimus? Aperiam cupiditate pariatur temporibus
                        voluptatem veritatis eaque molestias magni iusto tenetur
                        praesentium. Eum soluta quo dolorem expedita commodi unde.
                        Veritatis, omnis aliquid. Voluptate expedita harum minima dolorem
                        facilis, nemo quia.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the height of the header and/or footer together exceed viewport height - it sounds from the text that you want header, user chat stuff and footer all within the viewport, but what it that isn't possible?

Comment: i want all the information to always be in a window like in a chat and if the size of the chat-box or the chat-users increases overflow is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vh` unit to make the containers have a `max-height`.

I tried setting the `.main` div to `max-height: 100vh;` and the subcontainers to `max-height: 50vh;` or `40vh` combined with some `overflow-y: scroll;` and it seemed to do the trick.

CodeSandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hypatia-x2vfti?file=/src/styles.css:0-918